# Fetching HKWorkout data using UUID

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am wondering if it is possible for me to fetch individual HKWorkout Samples using the UUID of an individual HKWorkout. I am getting an error when I try to use a predicate to compare the workouts uuid. Any ideas?

```
func saveWorkout(workoutToSave: HKSample){
    let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .running)
    let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", workoutToSave.uuid.uuidString) //Gives error on runtime
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [workoutPredicate, idPredicate])
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(), predicate: compoundPredicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) { (sampleQuery, samplesFound, error) in
        if samplesFound != nil{
            print("Printing workout samples")
            print(samplesFound)
        }
    }
    database.healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. All you need to do is create a special HKQuery predicate.

```
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObject(with: UUID)
```